# How long can I soak dried beans before they are considered inedible?

Tags: food-safety, beans

How long (days/weeks) can beans that have only been soaked in the refrigerator last before they are considered inedible/spoiled? I found  black beans in the fridge that had been soaking for approx 3 weeks. They look and smell fine. Considering that they are dried beans soaking, toss or eat?

Comment: That's probably all of $1 of food—if that. Please keep that in mind when deciding if you want to eat food you're unsure of the safety of.

Comment: @derobert: True, but it's the principle of the matter! :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you cook to 180 and there is no smell of rotting at all when you drain them (before the cook) you should be good.  There aren't very many bacteria that rock out on dried beans and the few that do don't leave toxins behind, and the cold temp should have inhibited the rot.  If they do smell after the drain, I would pitch them.